# How to fix: "Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: Envelope FROM 'example@example.com' email address not allowed."

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email, smtp

I'm trying to make a contact form on my website with SMTP JS. However, when I submit info into the form it's not working outputting error message: "SMTP JS Contact Form Says "Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: Envelope FROM 'example@example.com' email address not allowed."

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
  <form onsubmit="send(); reset(); return false;">
            <input placeholder="First Name" required id="first-name"><br>
            <input placeholder="Last Name" required id="last-name"><br>
            <input placeholder="Email Adress" required id="email"><br>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
```

SMTP JS

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
<script>
var send = function() {
    Email.send({
    Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com",
    Username : "example@example.com",
    Password : "My Password",
    To : 'example@example.com',
    From : document.getElementById("email").value,
    Subject : "New Signup!!!",
    Body : "And this is the body"
}).then(
  message => alert(message)
);
};
    </script>
```

I've tried moving the website to https server as well as local host. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to use an actual email account to send the email. You should move sending the emajl to the backend though. [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) it's pretty simple to set up.

Comment: @ChrisG — smtp.js is a third-party backend and (although obfuscated for the question) it looks like credentials for an actual email account are being provided..

Comment: Isn't the error message just saying that the email address being read from the `document.getElementById("email").value` isn't allowed to send email from the account you've provided the credentials of? (My SMTP isn't quite good enough for me to be confident enough to claim that as an answer).

Comment: When I send out emails from contact forms, the FROM address usually has to be the one doing the sending. This is done to prevent people from faking the sender. You can however set an arbitrary email as Reply-To, which is where I put the sender's email they enter into the form. In other words, you need `From: "example@example.com"`, and you can try adding `ReplyTo: document.getElementById("email").value,`

Comment: @Chris G I tried adding ReplyTo: document.getElementById("email").value, and I still get the same error what else can I try?

Comment: I put my actual email as Username and From and it worked on the spot. Are you still getting the same error message?

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered the same issue while using it. I realised if the value of from is different from the value for username, it gives of that error. so i realised or rather presumed since its not actually sent from the users email that seems reasonable to occur so if you need to get the users email just send it together with the body

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I was testing SMTP JS too and realized the from address MUST be an actual email. What elasticemail does is bounce the mail.
So if you try this with an existing mail will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find a satisfying answer here, so I'll try to explain what worked for me :

In your elasticemail email API settings, you should make sure you registered and verified the email address / domain name you are trying to use as sender.

By default, the email you used to create your elasticemail account should appear here as "verified" (for me it was gmail and my gmail address). So if you use this same email as sender in the smtpJS config, it should actually work by default I guess.

BUT if you are trying to use a different email then you HAVE to verify it as well as the domain name if it is a specific domain name. It is explained in the elasticemail faq :
https://help.elasticemail.com/en/articles/4934400-how-to-verify-your-domain

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Two changes needed,

1. You have to use the password of the server you have created. (Not your Elasticemail account password)
2. Swap `To` and `From` emails like below,

and then it will work.

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
<script>
var send = function() {
    Email.send({
    Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com",
    Username : "example@example.com",
    Password : "Password for the server created in the Elasticemail",
    From : 'example@example.com',
    To : document.getElementById("email").value,
    Subject : "New Signup!!!",
    Body : "And this is the body"
}).then(
  message => alert(message)
);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com",
                    Username : "liquiddevelopercc@gmail.com",//username from 
                    elasticemail
                    Password : "*******",//password from elasticemail SMTP
                    From : 'liquiddevelopercc@gmail.com',//username from 
                    elasticemail
                    To: 'liquiddevelopercc@gmail.com',//prefered email addresss.
                    ReplyFrom : document.getElementById("email").value,// user 
                    email displays here in the mail box
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The 2-step verification should be on your gmail account then do email verification in elasticemail website.